# Java Annotation Processor, Processing Order

Tags: java, annotations, preprocessor

I'm wondering if there is a way to process annotations from top down in a class, or at least in some deterministic order.

It doesn't seem like this is the case because the [Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) class only provides:

```
boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv);
```

Where the [RoundEnvironment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html) allows you to access a `Set` of annotated elements, e.g.:

```
Set<? extends Element>  getElementsAnnotatedWith(TypeElement a)
```

Everything  is in terms of unordered collections, and this makes the order of processing unpredictable. Is there anyway around this, besides trying to sort manually by element name or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, there is not a way to force processing of annotations in a specified order, using the current interfaces.

Here is a workaround.  Suppose that you wish to process every declaration annotation, such as annotations on fields and methods.  Don't register any callback for those declarations.  Instead, invoke the annotation processor for every class.  The annotation processor obtains the AST from javac, then walks it in the order you prefer.  As an example, the [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) uses this implementation strategy.

This workaround might not be sufficient for your needs, because it still processes each class in an arbitrary order -- for instance, one that depends on javac's staged compilation model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious how ordering is done in auto/AutoValue project. They generate a POJO, where the constructor parameters are guaranteed to  have the same order as the abstract methods in the class. Do they achieve this using the process you describe above?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how that tool works -- you could investigate its [source code](https://github.com/google/auto/).  In practice, a compiler such as javac gives you the members in a deterministic order, but according to the annotation processing specification, it is allowed to change in the future.  I wouldn't expect it to, but you don't have a guarantee.

Comment: FWIW this is how AutoValue does it: https://github.com/google/auto/blob/6dde49040ffbd2ce644f280a70180948666046f8/value/src/main/java/com/google/auto/value/processor/EclipseHack.java#L52. Looks like the order can be trusted for everything but Eclipse, go figure.